# Как добавить вычисляемое поле в datagridView? C# + MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

Таблица содержит 7 полей, в каждом из которых содержатся "X" или "O". Как добавить вычисляемое поле в Datagridview, которое бы считало общее количество "X" по каждой строке? (пример на картинке)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При чём здесь MySql? | Из какой GUI-библиотеки DataGridView? Как данные попадают в этот грид: напрямую или с помощью привязки данных?

Answer (score 1):

<s>Строки должны добавлять только динамически

При событии добавления строки должна запускаться функция, которая вешает привязку события на каждую ячейку, следящего за изменением ячеек (кроме последней), что-то вроде:</s>

```
rowaddedevent(object s, DataGridViewCellEventArgs a)
{
  datagridrow row = somehow get new row();
  for (int i = 0; i < row.cells.Count - 1; i++)
  {
    var cell = row.cells[i];
    cell.onvaluechange += (s,a) => rowcellvaluechanged(row);
  }
}
```

Сама функция пересчёта и вывода результата:

```
void rowcellvaluechanged(row)
{  
  int result = 0;  
  for (int i = 0; i < row.cells.Count - 1; i++)  
  {  
    if (row.cells[i].Value == "X") result += 1;  
  }  
  row.cells[row.cells.Count-1].value = result;  
}
```

Это самый простой вариант, что приходит в голову.

---

Ошибся немного, у отдельных ячеек нет данного события, оно есть у каждой ячейки на всю таблицу по-умолчанию.
Следовательно функции rowaddedevent и rowcellvaluechanged не нужны.
Достаточно повесить следующую функцию на событие "CellValueChanged" таблицы:

```
cellschanged(s,a)
{
    if (datagridview.Columns.Count - 1 == a.ColumnIndex) return;
    var row = dt.Rows[a.RowIndex];
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (row.Cells[i].Value == "X") result += 1;
    }
    row.Cells[row.Cells.Count - 1].Value = result;
}
```

Comment: этот код не скомпилируется

Comment: @aepot исправил